# Can I use a multimeter to measure voltage even if amps of circuit is too high

Tags: voltage, current, multimeter

I need to measure circuits which I expect to be 12V 19A and 5V 44A

I've got a basic multi-meter which can handle 10A/ 240V

Can I use this multi-meter to measure only the voltage on the circuits? As the amps are too high; if I try to measure amps; my multi-meter will blow, but would just measuring volts be safe for the multi-meter?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DMMs in voltage mode typically have an input impedance of 10Mohm. When put across a 12V source this means that only 1.2µA will flow. This is well within what the DMM can handle.